# image gallery in asp.net c# in folder-file structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-gallery

Hello fellow programmers.
I am developing a website that has an image gallery. For example, if there is an event and pertaining to that event there are ten photos, I want user to be able to create a directory(album) in server representing that event and those ten images be stored in that folder with an album cover.
I am not actually storing images into database but only their path.
Suppose if i have folder- Images i want that user can create an album that becomes subfolder in Images and upload images into that folder. Further i want to be able to retrieve those albums and photos in it.
This is the first time i am trying it so i am not very clear as to how to proceed with it.
I only expect the steps i need to carry out to achieve it. I will develop the code. Facebook gallery can be considered as example of album-photos style.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: la die da .. what have you tried ? show us some code

Comment: i have referred this website to get idea..[link]http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/232_Picasa_Style_Photo_Album_Using_ListView_Control_in_ASPNet_35.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this: with, or without a database.

With a database, then you'd store the image files within the DB itself (generally inadvisable for performance reasons) and all the meta-data, including parent album information, in the database. If you don't want to store images in the DB then you can store them in a flat directory (each file would have the same filename as its DB record's primary key, so you won't get collisions).

Without a database, then each filesystem directory becomes the equivalent of an album, though the metadata you can store is limited (just the filename really). You could try to expose (and possibly edit) any embedded EXIF data but you'll probably run into problems.

The solution you've provided yourself in your Question actually provides disadvantages of both options: you're using a database, but you want to group images by album in the filesystem too? There's no advantage to that (and it also makes it impossible to cross-reference images into multiple albums).

Comment: any suggestion sir then how i proceed with it?